# Unity: Fish with rigid body leaving water

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am making a simulation of some fish in a lake.

I am using rigid body as otherwise they move through the sides. But when they hit into the sides they rotate and then the script I have to set their rotation to 0,0,0 when they leave fails.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be occurred by the fact that you are using unity's physics to move the fish but trying to set rotation directly. In this case movement and rotation of the fish are driven by Physics and forces, applied to the object. But you still can affect rotation and position if you reset all forces. Try looking [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/remove-all-force-innertia-from-a-rigidbody.25026/) to learn how to remove forces.

Also when dealing with Physics in Unity, don't mess Update() and FixedUpdate() methods, because it may lead to an incorrect result.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "hit into the sides" do you mean the sides of the simulated lake?
If so, one option might be to set the objects that denote the sides as "kinematic." Then you can detect when a GameObject (such as a fish) collides with it but it won't cause any physics reaction.
(ref: [RigidBody](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html))